# Why is this flux zero?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the vector field $\vec{F}=(x^2+y+2+z^2, e^{x^2}+y^2, x+3)$ and $S$ the part of the spherical surface $\{x^2+y^2+(z-a)^2=4a^2\}$ that is above the $x,y$-plane, with orientation outwards. I know that the flux of $F$ through $S$ is $-9\pi a^2$, because the flux through the bottom is $9\pi a^2$ and the flux through the whole closed surface is $0$.

But why is the flux through the whole closed surface zero?

Edit: I know I can use the divergence theorem to find the flux, but I don't know how to compute this and why this results in zero.

Comment: Note that $\text{div } F = 2(x + y)$. Now, the volume over which you are integrating is symmetric about $x  = y = 0$, so the integral will be zero. To show that formally, you might find it easiest to use spherical polars centered about $(0,0,a)$.

Comment: The divergence is the trace of the gradient and it becomes as Simon calculated. Maybe more helpful is $div {\vec F}  = \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}$.

Comment: To clarify Simon's answer you know that each point on opposite side of the sphere will have 2(-x-y) which in the integral will sum with the first point 2(x+y). Since this happens pairwise for all points, the integral becomes 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can try divergence theorem to find the flux through the whole sphere.

The divergence by computation is $2x+2y$. The integration is over the ball with spherical coordinate

$$x=2\rho \cos\theta \sin\phi\\
y=2\rho \sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z=a+2\rho\cos\phi$$

After setting up the integral, you will see that the integral with respect to $\theta$ is zero. So you don't need to compute the whole integral.

Comment: See my edit! :)